# I can't do a Binding with formGroup in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

Can any one help me please?
[HTML Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZQEM.png)

[Error in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIZ9R.png)

[Component.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeoA4.png)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JosefKatič  You can see the problem in the attached images

Comment: Yeah, but the link can expire by time and they can become unaccessible and this question could lost value.

Comment: According to those images are you sure you are importing it to the right module?

Comment: Thank you, it wasn't in the right module

Comment: But still please try to improve the question. You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to those images the error appear because the `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` are imported only in the `AppModule` but they are missing in the module where the `[formGroup]` is used.

**To make it work properly** you need to import `ReactiveFormsModule` **into all modules** that uses `[formGroup]` or `[formControlName]` or some validation. The `FormsModules` is used for example by `[(ngModel)]`.